# Ошибка при построении. Invalid pointer operation.

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Выскочила неожиданная ошибка.

[Error] Unit1.pas(191): Statement expected but 'PROCEDURE' found

С чем это может быть связано?

Часть кода

```
procedure TForm1.CheckBox2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if checkBox2.Checked = true then
  edit3.Enabled := true
else
  edit3.Enabled := false;
end;
```

И ещё такой вопрос. Программа работает нормально, но после выполнения опред действия выскакивает ошибка "Invalid poiner operation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

скорее всего у вас в предыдущей процедуре незакрыты какие-то операторные скобки(begin end).

Comment: Да точно. Спасибо.